Sass color.mix method not working with variable
I have the following mixin:
@mixin createGradient($prefix, $startColor, $endColor, $steps: 20) {

  $stepSize: 1000 / $steps;
  $stepPercentage: $stepSize / 1000;
  $stepsLoop: $steps - 1;

  @for $i from 1 through $stepsLoop {
    $color: mix($startColor, $endColor, (1 - ($stepPercentage * $i)));
    --#{$prefix}-color-step-#{$stepSize * $i}: $color;
  }
}

When I call it like so:
:root {
  body {
    --color1: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --color2: rgb(0, 0, 0);

    @include createGradient('example', var(--color1), var(--color2));
  }
}

I get the error:
✘ [ERROR] $color1: var(--color1) is not a color.
   ╷
   │                 $color: mix($startColor, $endColor, (1 - ($stepPercentage * $i)));

What I expect to happen is for rgb method to return a Color, which seems to not happen, currently.

you cannot use CSS variables with SASS. SASS is compiled before CSS enter in play.

@TemaniAfif do you reckon there's any alternative to what I want to accomplish?

https://css-tip.com/color-shades-color-mix/
